# Deploy with single file using distillery?

Tags: elixir, distillery

### Background

I have an OTP Application that I now need to deploy. To achieve this, I am using distillery. My objective is to pass a self-sufficient file to the PROD machine that contains everything and doesn’t need to be extracted.

### The usual route

Most people using distillery will know the usual route:

1. Run `MIX_ENV=prod mix release`
2. Copy the tarball in `build/prod/rel/<name>/releases/<version>/<name>.tar.gz` to the deploy server
3. Extract the tarbal
4. Run the code.

### Objective

My objective is to eliminate step 3. I don’t want to extract anything, I just want to copy the release and run it, like a sudo executable.

### –executable

According to the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/Mix.Tasks.Release.html) one can also run `MIX_ENV=prod mix release --executable` or `MIX_ENV=prod mix release --transient`. This will create a pseudo executable file that doesn’t need to be extracted.

### Question

However, after running the `MIX_ENV=prod mix release --executable` command, I usually search the file `build/prod/rel/<name>/releases/<version>/<name>.run`. In theory this should be the file I need to copy into my deploy server but I can’t find it anywhere.

- Which file do I need to copy into the deploy server and where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try double checking what you're doing. For reference, I just tried this, and it worked fine. I'm using Elixir 1.7.4 and distillery 2.0.12.

Here's what I did:

1. create a new project:

   ```
   mix new test_executable --sup
   ```
2. added distillery to `mix.exs`,
3. ran

   ```
   mix release.init
   ```
4. ran:

   ```
   env MIX_ENV=prod mix release --executable
   ```

   Got this output:

   ```
   ==> Assembling release..
   ==> Building release test_executable:0.1.0 using environment prod
   ==> Including ERTS 10.2 from /usr/local/Cellar/erlang/21.2/lib/erlang/erts-10.2
   ==> Packaging release..
   Release successfully built!
   To start the release you have built, you can use one of the following tasks:

       # start a shell, like 'iex -S mix'
       > _build/prod/rel/test_executable/bin/test_executable.run console

       # start in the foreground, like 'mix run --no-halt'
       > _build/prod/rel/test_executable/bin/test_executable.run foreground

       # start in the background, must be stopped with the 'stop' command
       > _build/prod/rel/test_executable/bin/test_executable.run start

   If you started a release elsewhere, and wish to connect to it:

       # connects a local shell to the running node
       > _build/prod/rel/test_executable/bin/test_executable.run remote_console

       # connects directly to the running node's console
       > _build/prod/rel/test_executable/bin/test_executable.run attach

   For a complete listing of commands and their use:

       > _build/prod/rel/test_executable/bin/test_executable.run help
   ```
5. I can now copy the file elsewhere and run it:

   ```
   cp _build/prod/rel/test_executable/bin/test_executable.run /tmp
   cd /tmp
   ./test_executable.run console
   Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

   Interactive Elixir (1.7.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
   iex(test_executable@127.0.0.1)1>
   ```